# Goal Unsupported by Tactic

Tags: z3

I have some code, which I want to check with help of some tactics. Since I have lot of `if-then-else` statements, I want to apply `elim-term-ite` tactic.

I have made use of following tactics

`(check-sat-using (then (! simplify :arith-lhs true) elim-term-ite solve-eqs lia2pb pb2bv bit-blast sat))`

However, if I an error with this as - `"goal is in a fragment unsupported by lia2pb"`

So then, if I try to remove the tactics `lia2pb` and the ones next to them, I get another error as `unknown "incomplete"`.

I tried to remove all the tactics except for the `simplify`, however I would still get an `incomplete` error.

What is that I should try to help the sat solver solve the problem?
Should I try another tactics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use `lia2pb` (aka linear integer arithmetic to pseudo-boolean), all integer variables must be bounded. That is, they must have a lower and upper bound.

The tactic `sat` is only complete if the input goal does not contain theory atoms. That is, the goal contains only Boolean connectives and Boolean constants. If that is not the case, then it will return "unknown" if it cannot show the (Boolean abstraction of the input) goal to be unsatisfiable.

You can ask Z3 to display the input goal for `lia2pb` by using the following command:

```
(apply (then (! simplify :arith-lhs true) elim-term-ite solve-eqs)
```

If some of your formulas contain unbounded integer variables, you can build a strategy that reduces to SAT when possible, and invokes a general purpose solver otherwise. This can be accomplished using the `or-else` combinator. Here is an example:

```
(check-sat-using (then (! simplify :arith-lhs true) elim-term-ite solve-eqs 
                       (or-else (then lia2pb pb2bv bit-blast sat)
                                smt)))
```

**EDIT:** The tactic `lia2pb` also assumes that the lower bound of every bounded integer variable is zero. This is not a big problem in practice, since we can use the tactic `normalize-bounds` before applying `lia2pb`. The tactic `normalize-bounds` will replace a bound variable `x` with `y + l_x`, where `y` is a fresh variable and `l_x` is the lower bound for x. For example, in a goal containing `3 <= x`, `x` is replaced with `y+3`, where `y` is a new fresh variable.

Comment: so suppose if I check using this formula `(check-sat-using (then (! simplify :arith-lhs true) solve-eqs (! add-bounds :add-bound-upper 100000) elim-term-ite))` why would I still get `unknown "incomplete"`?

Comment: The tactic `add-bounds` is a under-approximation. That is, after applying this tactic, a satisfiable goal may become unsatisfiable. For example, assume the input goal only had a solution where some unbounded variable `x` is assigned to `100001`. This goal becomes unsatisfiable after the tactic adds the constraint `x <= 100000`. Thus, the tactic `add-bounds` should only be used in model-finding strategies. That is, we are looking for small solutions for an integer problem. Moreover, for this given strategy, we can intepret unknown as: the problem does not have a small solution.