# Why does Z3 return unknown for this nonlinear integer arithmetic example?

Tags: z3, smt

I have a simple example in nonlinear integer arithmetic, namely a search for Pythagorean triples.  Based on what I read in related questions (see below), I'd expect Z3 to find a solution to this problem, but it returns 'unknown'.  Here is the example in SMT-LIB v2:

```
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun y () Int)
(declare-fun z () Int)
(declare-fun xSquared () Int)
(declare-fun ySquared () Int)
(declare-fun zSquared () Int)
(declare-fun xSquaredPlusYSquared () Int)

(assert (= xSquared (* x x)))
(assert (= ySquared (* y y)))
(assert (= zSquared (* z z)))
(assert (= xSquaredPlusYSquared (+ xSquared ySquared)))

(assert (and (> x 0) (> y 0) (> z 0) (= xSquaredPlusYSquared zSquared)))

(check-sat)

(exit)
```

---

There are a few related questions, most notably:

- [How does Z3 handle non-linear integer arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898175/how-does-z3-handle-non-linear-integer-arithmetic)
- [Need help understanding the equation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326306/need-help-understanding-the-equation/12327648#12327648)
- [Combining nonlinear Real with linear Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661446/combining-nonlinear-real-with-linear-int)
- [Z3 support for nonlinear arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064822/z3-supports-for-nonlinear-arithmetics)
- [z3 limitations in handling nonlinear real arithmetics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13711351/z3-limitations-in-handling-nonlinear-real-arithmetics)

Comment: The answer seems to be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481347/goal-unsupported-by-tactic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Z3 won't attempt finding a solution by bit-blasting unless variables have a finite range. Replacing `(check-sat)` with the following command will find the solution:

```
(check-sat-using (then (using-params add-bounds :add-bound-lower -100 :add-bound-upper 100) smt))
```

Alternatively, one can add assert statements forcing each variable to have some finite range.