# Representing temporal constraints in SMT-LIB

Tags: logic, z3, smt, temporal

I'm trying to represent temporal constraints in SMT-LIB in order to check their satisfiability. I'm looking for feedback on the direction I'm taking. I'm relatively new to SMT-LIB and I'll highly appreciate inputs.

The constraints that I have are about the time and duration of events. For example, consider the following constraints given in natural language:

1. John started writing an essay at 13:03:41, and it took him 20 min to complete it.
2. After writing, he checked his emails, which took him more than 40 min.
3. After checking his emails, he phoned his wife.
4. He phoned his wife after 14:00:00.

It is easy to see that this set of constraints is staisfiable and I'm trying to deduce that using an SMT solver.

To have some sore of encapsulation for the concepts of time and duration I defined new sorts that represent them in arrays. Some macros were defined for acting as constructions:

```
(define-sort Time () (Array Int Int))
(define-fun new_time_ns ((hours Int) (minutes Int) (seconds Int) (nanos Int)) Time
    (store (store (store (store ((as const (Array Int Int)) 0) 1 hours) 2 minutes) 3 seconds) 4 nanos)
)
(define-sort Duration () (Array Int Int))
(define-fun new_duration_ns ((seconds Int) (nanos Int)) Duration
    (store (store ((as const (Array Int Int)) 0) 1 seconds) 2 nanos)
)
```

Getters are defined using macros and allow us to retrieve specific measures, for instance:

```
(define-fun getDurationSecond ((d Duration)) Int
  (select d 1)
)

(define-fun getDurationNano ((d Duration)) Int
  (select d 2)
)
```

Some utility macros were defined for time and duration arithmetic and for expressing relations. For example, using some helper macros we define ***isLongerThan***, ***isShorterThan*** and ***isEqualDuration***  as follows:

```
(define-fun cmpInt ((i1 Int) (i2 Int)) Int
  (ite (< i1 i2) -1 (ite(> i1 i2) 1 0))
) 

(define-fun cmpDuration ((d1 Duration) (d2 Duration)) Int
  (ite (= (cmpInt (getDurationSecond d1) (getDurationSecond d2)) 0) 
    (ite (= (cmpInt (getDurationNano d1) (getDurationNano d2)) 0)
    0
    (cmpInt (getDurationNano d1) (getDurationNano d2)))
  (cmpInt (getDurationSecond d1) (getDurationSecond d2)))
)  

(define-fun isLongerThan ((d1 Duration) (d2 Duration)) Bool
  (> (cmpDuration d1 d2) 0)
)

(define-fun isShorterThan ((d1 Duration) (d2 Duration)) Bool
  (< (cmpDuration d1 d2) 0)
)

(define-fun isEqualDuration ((d1 Duration) (d2 Duration)) Bool
  (= (cmpDuration d1 d2) 0)
)
```

The rest of the definitions can be found in [this file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21642925/TempTest.smt2).

Based on this I can express the constraints by a set of assertions:

```
(declare-const write_start Time)
(declare-const write_end Time)
(declare-const write_duration Duration)

(declare-const check_start Time)
(declare-const check_end Time)
(declare-const check_duration Duration)

(declare-const phone_start Time)

(assert (= write_start (new_time_ns 13 03 41 0)))  ; the writing started at 13:03:41
(assert (= write_duration (new_duration 1200)))    ; the writing took 20 min (1200 sec).
(assert (= write_end (plusDuration write_start write_duration)))

(assert (isAfter check_start write_end))                   ; the check started after the writing
(assert (isLongerThan check_duration (new_duration 2400))) ; the check took more than 40 min
(assert (= check_end (plusDuration check_start check_duration)))

(assert (isAfter phone_start check_end))                   ; he phoned after the check
(assert (isAfter phone_start (new_time_ns 14 00 00 0)))    ; it was after 14:00:00

(check-sat)
```

Some questions and problems:

1. Design-wise, I'd be interested to know whether this is a reasonable modeling of the problem in SMT-LIB.
2. Some notes to add here: (A) I decided to use arrays to represent the time and duration objects since they help to group the internal fields of these concepts (hours, minutes, seconds, nanos). Individual integers could be used just as well. (B) I'm relying on macros (define-fun ...) very heavily, and this could make the constraints a bit complicated, but I don't know what else could be used for reaching the required level of expressiveness and clarity that the current code has. (C) Currently there are no constraints that limit the time fields, so the value of the minutes field, for example, can be 78. Assertions should be added that restrict the seconds to 59, the minutes to 59, and the hours to 23, but I didn't find an elegant way to do that.
3. I assume that I'm in a decidable fragment of FOL - QF_LIA - since all constraints are declared using linear functions over integer constants. However, I tried to run [the attached code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21642925/TempTest.smt2) through Z3 and even after 40 minutes of running locally on average computer it still doesn't return with a resolution (sat/unsat). I actually don't know if it can solve the problem at all. It's possible that my assumption of being in QF-LIA is wrong and it's also possible that Z3 struggles with this type of constraints. I can add that When I tried simpler constraints Z3 managed to reach a resolution but I noticed that the models it generated were very complicated with lots of internal structures. Could someone please give me some ideas to investigate here? Z3's online prover with my code can be found [here](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/yWUJs). I haven't tried other SMT solvers yet.
4. I'm unaware of parallel works that try to define temporal constraints of this type in SMT-LIB. I'd really appreciate references to existing works.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are already familiar with CLTL (Constraint Linear Temporal Logic) and able to model your problem in CLTL, you can use Zot and my plugin ae2bvzot. https://github.com/fm-polimi/zot
It automatically translates the CLTL formula into smt2, runs Z3 and renders the result with assignment for each variable in each time instant.

Comment: You can restrict Z3 to a particular logic, for instance by using `(set-logic QF_LIA)` Z3 will complain if your problem does not fit quantifier-free linear integer arithmetic.

Comment: If in addition you use arrays, then `(set-logic QF_AUFLIA)`. However your use of arrays _may_ be part of the problem. If you can write an uglier SMT problem without using arrays, I am pretty sure that Z3 will solve it much faster. Adding more theories to your spec can only make things worse, so try to express your problem using just `QF_LIA`.

Comment: @mmpourhashem, thanks for the information and for offering your tool. I'm not familiar with CLTL, I'll look into that. Could you please point me to some introductory text or tutorial?

Comment: @iago, yes, I also tried to run it with the set-logic command, but no avail. I spent some time testing Z3, CVC4 and Yices, each of which with and without arrays (i.e. in QF_ALIA and QF_LIA). All combinations work fine except for Z3 with arrays. It seems to me like a Z3 issue. I'm attaching my code, in case someone wants to look into that. [Array code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21642925/TempTest_Array.smt2) /[Array-Free code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21642925/TempTest_ArrayFree.smt2)

Comment: @Assaf 
In the [Zot distribution](https://github.com/fm-polimi/zot/tree/master/doc) you can find the manual and an installation guide.
In the paper [Constraint LTL satisfiability checking without automata](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.0946.pdf) you can find all the details about CLTL (but you do not need all of it).
The manual can be a good starting point.

Comment: @Assaf if you have a benchmark that CVC4 and Yices solve and Z3 does not, you may consider opening an issue on Z3's issue tracker (cf. https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like your approach, but I think your over-complicating the situation by defining your own sorts, and especially by using an array theory.

Also, mathematically, the integer theories are harder than their real counterparts.  For example "*n = pq*, solve for *p*" is trivial if *n*, *p*, and *q* are reals, but if they're integers then it's integer factoring, which is hard. Similarly *x<sup>n</sup> + y<sup>n</sup> = z<sup>n</sup>, n > 2* is easy to solve in the reals, but in the integers, that's Fermat's last theorem.  These examples are nonlinear, but I claim you're better-off to be in QF_LRA than QF_LIA, if you consider that the techniques used to solve QF_LRA are taught to middle-school and high-school students.  Time is closer to a real number than it is to a bunch of integers, anyway.

In my experience with SMT solvers in general and Z3 in particular, you're better off to use a simpler theory. It will permit Z3 to use its most powerful internal solvers.  If you use more sophisticated theories like arrays, you might get a spectacular result, or you might find that the solver times out and you have no idea why, as was the case with your proposed solution.

It's not as nice from a software engineering point of view, but mathematically I recommend the following simple solution to the problem you posed, where all times are represented as real numbers, in terms of the number of seconds since midnight on the day of interest:

```
; Output all real-valued numbers in decimal-format.
(set-option :pp.decimal true)

; Convenience function for converting hh:mm:ss formatted times to seconds since midnight.
(define-fun time_hms ((hour Real) (minute Real) (second Real)) Real
    (+ (+ (* 3600.0 hour) (* 60.0 minute)) second)
)

; Convenience function for converting durations in minutes to seconds.
(define-fun duration_m ((minute Real)) Real
    (* 60.0 minute)
)

; Variable declarations. Durations are in seconds. Times are in seconds since midnight.
(declare-fun write_start () Real)
(declare-fun write_end () Real)
(declare-fun write_duration () Real)
(declare-fun check_start () Real)
(declare-fun check_end () Real)
(declare-fun check_duration () Real)
(declare-fun phone_start () Real)

; Constraints.

; 1. John started writing an essay at 13:03:41, and it took him 20 min to complete it.
(assert (= write_start (time_hms 13 03 41)))
(assert (= write_duration (duration_m 20)))
(assert (= write_end (+ write_start write_duration)))

; 2. After writing, he checked his emails, which took him more than 40 min.
(assert (> check_start write_end))
(assert (> check_duration (duration_m 40)))
(assert (= check_end (+ check_start check_duration)))

; 3. After checking his emails, he phoned his wife.
(assert (> phone_start check_end))

; 4. He phoned his wife after 14:00:00.
(assert (> phone_start (time_hms 14 00 00)))

(check-sat)
(get-value (write_start write_duration write_end check_start check_end check_duration phone_start))
(exit)
```

Both Z3 and CVC4 quickly find a solution:

```
sat
((write_start 47021.0)
 (write_duration 1200.0)
 (write_end 48221.0)
 (check_start 48222.0)
 (check_end 50623.0)
 (check_duration 2401.0)
 (phone_start 50624.0))
```

Comment: Many thanks for the ideas and for the explanation. This is what I was looking for. Since posting this question I made some progress and I do a very similar modeling. Regarding the Reals vs Integers issue, would it be correct to say that reals are at a disadvantage when we deal with bound quantification? An assertion with bound quantification over integers can be re-written by the pre-processor as a limited set of assertions over each possible value, but with reals the quantification is in fact infinite (since reals are dense) and can't be re-written, so the solving process will be much harder.

Comment: I'm dealing with this question since I need to be able to prove claims about activities, such as "john started writing at 2pm and he wrote for 2 hours" => "John wrote at 2:30pm.". I currently work with integers, and I define a function 'write' and an assertion that for each timestamp between the start time and the end time, the function returns True, and otherwise False. In this way it is easily provable that at the time stamp of 2:30pm the function returns True.

Comment: The reason for using quantification at all is that some events are activities and say that something happen all along a certain time stamp (i.e. universal quantification), and some events are occurrences and say that something happened instantly at some point during a time stamp (i.e. existential quantification). To illustrate the contrast, an activity "John was writing before he had lunch at 1pm" allows to infer that "John was writing at 12:30pm", but an occurrence "John met Mary before they had lunch at 1pm" does not allow to infer that "john met Mary at 12:30pm".

Comment: Yes, sometimes one can prove certain things more easily over the integers if all variables are bound to finite ranges, such that the integers can be enumerated. If you are restricting your time ranges to one day or less, and if minute or second resolution is good enough for you, then you might get good enough performance from an approach like that.

Comment: Finite ranges can be enforced either using assertions, or by replacing `(check-sat)` with `(check-sat-using...` plus the appropriate options.  See this question/answer of mine for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281590/why-does-z3-return-unknown-for-this-nonlinear-integer-arithmetic-example/33286988#33286988