# Discrete time steps in Z3 / CVC4 / SMT-LIB

Tags: z3, smt, cvc4

I am defining time steps using an Int in SMT-LIB, which forces me to assert things to make sure nothing happens in the negatives:

```
(declare-sort Pkg) ; A package
(define-sort Time () Int) ; The installation step
; ...
(assert (forall ((t Time) (p Pkg)) (=> (< t 0) (not (installed p t)))))
```

I saw that in Z3 we can define inductive `Nat`s in the usual style. Would it be good to use the inductive definition of `Nat` or is there a better way of doing what I am trying to do above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really stick to `Int`, and put in `>= 0` constraints appropriately. Z3 knows a lot about `Int`, has all sorts of proof rules and tricks to deal with it. While you can indeed define an inductive `Nat` type, you'll lose all the internal machinery for dealing with integers, and due to the recursive definition Z3's decision procedures will be less effective; especially in combination with other theories.

Having said that, it is impossible to know unless you try: There might be some problem domains where the inductive definition might fit better. But just by purely looking at the kind of you're problem dealing with, good old `Int` seems to be the right choice for you.

Also see this related question: [Representing temporal constraints in SMT-LIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592724/representing-temporal-constraints-in-smt-lib) which is definitely relevant in your context.

Comment: Thanks for your view. I had seen the question you linked to (_Representing temporal constraints_), but I'm not sure how I would use Reals in my case, because I am looking at discrete steps like in a state machine. If I manage to use Reals anyway I'll feed back how that went.